# Save content of a div to new file with jQuery AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fwrite

I'm trying to save contents of a div to new html file.
I'm using jQuery AJAX to send data to php.
However, the php in its current form writes an empty file.

Html:

```
<div id="data2save">
     <span>data1</span>
     <span>data2</span>
     <span>data3</span>
     <span>data4</span>
</div>

<input type="button" value="save" id="save">
```

JQuery:

```
 $("#save").live("click",function() {

    var bufferId =$("#data2save").html();

            $.ajax({
                 method : "POST",
                 url : "saver.php",
                 data: {id : bufferId},
                 dataType: "html",
                 success: function(data){ 
                 alert("ok");  
                 }
                 });
 });
```

PHP:

```
 <?php
$handle = fopen("test.html", 'w+');
$data = $_POST['data'];
if($handle)
{

if(!fwrite($handle, $data ))
echo "ok";
}

?>
```

Comment: Just some questions to help you debug this problem: is the data arriving at the server? Does `$_POST['data']` ever get a value? Does `bufferId` get the right value? Does the `alert('ok');` ever run? By analyzing the problem like this, you can more accurately determine where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Request method property is `type` instead of `method` (`$.ajax({ method : "POST"` is actually `$.ajax({ type : "POST"`) and `$_POST['data']` should be `$_POST['id']`.

Comment: I find it easier to just use the shorthand $.post(url, data_obj) method.  Avoids these mistakes.  There's no need for dataType: "html"  either.

Answer (score 1):

There is no $_POST['data'] being posted, only $_POST['id'].  Look at this part:

```
data: {id : bufferId},
```