# Textarea Content to File

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to save the content of a textarea to a file.
I have written my script as illustrated in that topic:
[Save content of a div to new file with jQuery AJAX and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758738/save-content-of-a-div-to-new-file-with-jquery-ajax-and-php)
I just save the content of a textarea instead of the div.. And that works!
The problem is that only the text that is displayed in the textarea at the beginning is saved to the file. I want the changed text of the textarea to be saved.
Would be very nice if anyone can help me editing this script to make it work.

Regards
Markus

Comment: Have you tried using the `val()` property on the TextArea rather than the `html()`?

Comment: Please add some code of what you tried to do so far.

Comment: The code you linked to doesn't even have a textarea

Comment: `.val()` instead of `.html` worked! thx

Answer (score 0):

maybe you´re looking for something like this:

it will always save the actual text when it changes (as i understood you)

```
$("#data2save").change(function() {

var bufferId =$("#data2save").text();

        $.ajax({
             method : "POST",
             url : "saver.php",
             data: {id : bufferId},
             dataType: "html",
             success: function(data){ 
             alert("ok");  
             }
             });
});
```

if it´s not what youre looking for u definetly need to make use of .text() to retrieve the textares content

```
var bufferId =$("#data2save").text();
```

Comment: `.text()` didnt save the current content but
`.val()` brought the result i was looking for.