# How to save the content of a div to your site using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ob-get-contents

I have developed a HTML editor using codemirror. I am now searching for  a way to let users save the code what is inside the div to the site's server, so they can view their site. I searched on the internet and found this on the internet:

```
<?php 
// Start the buffering // 
ob_start(); 
?> 
Your page content bla bla bla bla ... 
<?php 
echo '1'; 
// Get the content that is in the buffer and put it in your file // 
file_put_contents('yourpage.html', ob_get_contents()); 
?>
```

Source:  [Save current page as HTML to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775281/save-current-page-as-html-to-server)

But now i am on a point: how can i save the content of the div into a html file on my server? I searched and found that on the line where it saids: "your page content bla bla bla bla" you have to use "", but it doesn't work. I am new to php so help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: just so i can understand better ... you have an html editor ... and when you hit save you want the content of that editor to be stored as an html page ? where you visitors can open ?

Comment: it's hard to past code without understand the basic it works => file_put_contents('yourpage.html', ob_get_contents()); **yourpage.html** will be created on your server. this is the point i understand your question

Comment: @KarimMagdyMansour Yes thats exactly what i mean!

Comment: Turn the input into a `<form>` input and `POST` it to your server on submit?

Comment: Save everything as a string?

Comment: Both thanks for the ideas, i didn't thought about that. I will look and try. THANKS!

Comment: what you do is pointless, however it will write the content to a file, it happens before user has any chance to edit, what you need to do is post request using ajax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758738/save-content-of-a-div-to-new-file-with-jquery-ajax-and-php

Comment: Wait, so you are going to let people create a html page, which will then be uploaded onto your server. I hope you are taking security seriously as allowing people you dont know to create content on your server might be a very bad idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)
read element of page by id, class & ...